# Deserialization issue for Scala.Symbol, in Scala 2.12 version, for Scala.Symbol Serialized in Scala 2.11

Tags: java, scala, serialization, deserialization

```
import java.io. {FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream}
object SymbolSerializeDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fileName = "file.ser"
    val symbolCheck: Symbol = Symbol("someSymbol")
    //serializeToFile(symbolCheck, fileName)
    deserializeFromFile(fileName)
  }
  private def serializeToFile(input: Symbol, fileName: String): Unit = {
    try {
      val file: FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)
      val out: ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(file)
      out.writeObject(input)
    }
  }
  private def deserializeFromFile(fileName: String): Unit = {
    try {
      val file: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName)
      val input: ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(file)
      val output = input.readObject.asInstanceOf[Symbol]
      println("Symbol after deseralization " + output.name)
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to deserialized scala symbol,  serialized in scala 2.11 but I am getting error as `java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.Symbol; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2966401305346518859, local class serialVersionUID = 6865603221856321286` Can we write custom serialization for this or any other option?

I tried adding serialVersionUID for class as well as for Symbol

Comment: Why do you need this? Why can't you deserialize in the same version as it was serialized?

Comment: We are working on migration of legacy project, when we restart the application, server keeps data in serialized form as restoration point. We can't loose this data. 

We have done the migration, everthing is working fine except class containing Scala.Symbol giving us this exceptions.  Thanks

Comment: Any chance you could first transform the `Symbol` to `String`?

Comment: No @GaëlJ, Symbol is used at many places.

Comment: Maybe retrieve the Symbol class java code generated for Scala 2.11 and copy/paste it with another name in your project? Not sure if that could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by downgrading scala version from 2.12.17 to 2.12.6.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run Scala 2.11 from Scala 2.12 for deserialization or will it be too slow?

```scala
// Scala 2.12
import sys.process._

Symbol("scala-2.11.12/bin/scala path_to_deserializer/Deserializer.scala path_to_file/file.ser".!!)
// 'someSymbol
```

```scala
// Deserializer.scala
import java.io.{FileInputStream, ObjectInputStream}

object Deserializer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    deserializeFromFile(args(0))
  }

  private def deserializeFromFile(fileName: String): Unit = {
    val file: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName)
    val input: ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(file)
    val output = input.readObject.asInstanceOf[Symbol]
    println(output.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmytro, Thanks for the information. This solution might work for this example however, in project, we will not be able to do it. In project , Akka server is doing serialization and deseralization. We can't force akka server to do it in this way. I have given this example to understand the problem. Currently, I am checking custom serialization. Thanks

Comment: @user3771712 Why?

Comment: Also , When akka serialized the object, it will be not having just symbols, it will have case classes, List, etc.

Comment: Hi Dmytro, 
  case class Mobile(name: String)
  case class Notification(m: Mobile, s: Symbol)
  val n = Notification(Mobile("Apple"), Symbol("someSymbol"))

Will this approach works for Deserialization of  "n"  
Thank.