# scala.Some(value) got deserialized into Some(null) if deserialized by using another scala version

Tags: scala, serialization, akka, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize an object stream with Scala 2.12.6 which has serialized using scala 2.11.11

Please check below case class which has optional fields.

```
@SerialVersionUID(123467891598L)
case class Initialiser(externalPID: Option[String], user: Option[String])
```

which I am serializing using scala 2.11.11 with values as follows

```
Initialiser(Option("Test"), Option("Test"))
```

then deserialized it with scala 2.12.6 where I am getting the following result

```
Initialiser(Some(null), Some(null))
```

I am losing the data during this process. I have used Akka `SerializationExtension` for this process

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue? I found the following details [at the Scala bug tracker](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12063) where it's mentioned that it's not supporting binary compatibility.

Is it possible to resolve these issues using any third-party library like Boopickle?

Comment: As you say, this is not supported. You need to switch to a more stable serialisation format such as JSON or Protocol Buffers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74460752/deserialization-issue-for-scala-symbol-in-scala-2-12-version-for-scala-symbol

Comment: hi @DmytroMitin it was same raised for earlier issue which has resolved by changing the library version and it was because of different serial version ids. Here we have same versions ids for scala.Some and scala.Option as it has not changed however Scala is not providing the binary compatibility and hence loosing the data

Comment: hi @Tim, we could loos the data for running processes if we change the approach and the impact will be same compared to current issue, hence trying to resolve the issue rather than changing the existing approach

Comment: You either need to have the library authors add backwards compatibility or you need to move to a format that has backwards compatibility. If you don't want to change the existing server then write a tool with 2.11.11 that reads the legacy format and writes a format that can be read by the new 2.12.6 code.